# Create a matrix from a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a vector `v`, and I would like to create the following matrix. How can I do this in R?

```
      v = c(1, 2, 3, 4)

      > m = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,4), nrow=4)
      > m
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
     [1,]    1    2    3    4
     [2,]    1    2    3    4
     [3,]    1    2    3    4
     [4,]    1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 4):

See `?matrix` and the `nrow`, `ncol`, `byrow` arguments:

```
matrix(v, nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
#[3,]    1    2    3    4
#[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: in `?matrix` the part "If there are too few elements in data to fill the matrix, then the elements in data are **recycled**." is important to understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
create_mat<-function(V,r,c){
   ans<- matrix(V, nrow = r, ncol = c, byrow =FALSE)
   return ans
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tcrossprod` to play a trick, where `v^0` generates a vector of `1`s

```
> tcrossprod(v^0,v)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    1    2    3    4
```